# How to use a username as part of the url in php

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let say I have a site

> www.mysite.com

Is there anyway to have to have user page urls be

> www.mysite.com/username

instead of the usual

> www.mysite.com/user.php?id=whatever

I would like to know if this is possible in php without having multiple folders and index pages. I would like to avoid the folder method because from my understanding you would have an issue with efficiency especially if you have to bounce from one user to another. I would like to do this method because it is a lot easier for someone to say get my info from

> www.mysite.com/username

than the other option. Any help (tutorials, sites, etc) would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up `.htaccess` rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure, use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It is important to note that this will mean that `mysite.com/every-page-that-does-not-exist` will forward to the user page.

Comment: Yes but there is no other way it can be written since OP wants `www.mysite.com/username`

Comment: can't you just do a condition for pages that don't exist and call the 404 page

Comment: @user2251229:  How would rewrite rule know whether `www.mysite.com/foo` is a valid user or not?

Comment: @user2251229: Would you be fine with a pretty user URL like `www.mysite.com/user/username` then it would be better 404 management?

Comment: @anubhava yeah I guess that would be better management but its not as pretty as www.mysite.com/username. Image your twitter was twitter.com/users/anubhava. I'll try both methods

Comment: Just a `/u/username` shouldn't be too bad

Answer (score 2):

> > I would like to know if this is possible in php without having multiple folders and index pages.

Yes, its possible. You can do it redirecting all requests to your index.php and process this url (route) manually

sample .htaccess for redirecting all request to your index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**BUT** implemention of

```
www.mysite.com/username
```

is not easy thing. You have to know all your system usrls such as /register, /login, /post, ... etc and dont allow to register these usernames. 
I recomend you implement this scheme:

`www.mysite.com/~username`
or
`www.mysite.com/user/username`

Comment: What do you mean the first implemenation is hard

Comment: Do you understand how does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern work ?


You declare patterns and process it.

In my schema you should declare next route:

`/~(\w+)` or `/user/(\w+)`

in the first implementation you need to check all your routes and if nothing found you should check "Maybe this is username"..

Comment: @AlexandrKapustin it is very easy if you use a framework with registered routes [e.g. Symfony or Rails]. Of course you first check for the system routes [which won't be that many], then for users.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) with any kind of router [e.g. [klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php)], then you'll need a single, universal `.htaccess` file in your webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```